# Xcode resize vector shape generated with paintcode

Tags: swift, frame, uibarbuttonitem, paintcode

I created a vector shape with Paintcode an the I need to draw the image into a BarButtonItem; i know that i have to use `myBarButtonItem.image = StyleKit.imageOfCanvas1(CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))`, but this is the result

[image]

So how can i do to solve this problem?

EDIT: here my Paintcode file https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0yl27fax0sn8ib/MenuBall.pcvd?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw a frame around your shape, if you already didn't do it. Then you need to specify how the shape behaves when resized. You can start here: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/documentation/frames#Frames

Comment: Just added the frame, and set the resize behavior (please take a look to my paint code file, maybe I've made a mistake)